# Installing Node.js on a remote LAMP server with no internet connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, node.js

As a part of a student project, I am to host my Node.js-based server application on a server so that other people can try connecting to it and test the integrity of it's functions. The problem is that the server I have been assigned is a LAMP server on a machine in a another city. The server in question has been cut of from the internet for security reasons, so I can only access it via ssh from the university's intranet.

My application requires Node.js, but since I have no internet connection, a manual install must be performed. The only way to do this is to send files to the server where the virtual server is hosted (with sftp), then place them in the directory which serves as home for my user on the virtual server.

With the above steps completed, the problems begin. Simply placing the precompiled binaries on the server doesn't work; it still has no idea that the library is installed on the server. I have tried sending the source to the server and compiling it remotely (with the ssh connection), but this returns the error: `Cannot open : Disk quota exceeded`. This is despite the fact that I have been assured that the virtual server should expand it's available space automatically.

Can anyone help me make sense of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would find out *exactly* what OS and CPU type the remote system is using, then build a local [VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) using the same OS and CPU type. Then build a working environment inside that, which you can then `tar` up and unpack on the remote system.

When building the software, I would make heavy use of `--prefix` options to `configure` scripts to force all binaries into a directory scheme of my choosing, such as `$HOME/myproject`, to make the whole thing portable.